# Section vs Articles for home page content

Tags: html

I am building an ecommerce website and I am not sure whether I am using the sections  and articles tag correctly for my home page content.

Here is my code :

```
<main>

 <article id="welcome-text">
  <h2>Welcome to XYZ</h2>
  <p></p>
 </article>

<article id="services">
  <h2>Our Services</h2>

  <section id="services-1">
  <h3>Serices1 Name</h3>
  <p>Serices1 Description</p>
  </section>

  <section id="services-2">
  <h3>Serices2 Name</h3>
  <p>Serices2 Description</p>
  </section>

 </article>

<article id="bestsellers">

<section id="product-1">
  <img src="img/product1.jpg" /> 
  <h3>Product1 Name</h3>
  <p>Product1 Description</p>
</section>

<section id="product-2">
  <img src="img/product2.jpg" />
  <h3>Product2 Name</h3>
  <p>Product2 Description</p>
</section>

<section id="product-3">
<img src="img/product3.jpg" />
  <h3>Product3 Name</h3>
  <p>Product3 Description</p>
</section>

</article>

</main>
```

Is my code semantically correct?

I know that articles are supposed to be  "independently distributable" and 
sections are a " thematic grouping of content". I have read a ton of articles regarding this and also checked out the home pages of several websites but its still so confusing. Thanks

Comment: I would swap them around. I always use articles to identify things and sections to group those things. The [MDN Article page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/article) also has a good example

Comment: You mean to say that "welcome-text", "services" and "bestsellers" need to sections and the content inside them should be split into articles? Thanks for the link though.

Comment: Yes. I always think "Is this part a thing on it's own?" Like a product, a comment or whatever and the part where all the comments are is kinda like a comment `section`. Luckily for the formatting it doesn't matter what you put where, but some devices or technologies could benefit from the right elements at the right place. [Here's the rest of MDN's pages about HTML5 semantics](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Semantics)